# Android Login Activity

Tags: android

I have an application android with login activity. my application work perfectly but after I login and I close my application and than I open it again I always must login first. I don't know how to make my program just login once time.

My code like this

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
TextView btnForgot;
Button btnLogin;
EditText inputEmail;
EditText inputPassword;
private TextView loginErrorMsg;
private TextView macmac, macmac1;
private ProgressDialog pDialog;
private static String KEY_SUCCESS = "success";
private static String KEY_UID = "uid";
private static String KEY_USERNAME = "uname";
private static String KEY_FIRSTNAME = "fname";
private static String KEY_LASTNAME = "lname";
private static String KEY_EMAIL = "email";
private static String KEY_CREATED_AT = "created_at";
private static String MAC = "mac_0";
JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
JSONArray products = null;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    btnForgot = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    inputEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
    inputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
    btnLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
    loginErrorMsg = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.loginErrorMsg);
    TypedValue typedValueColorPrimaryDark = new TypedValue();
    MainActivity.this.getTheme().resolveAttribute(R.attr.colorPrimary, typedValueColorPrimaryDark, true);
    final int colorPrimaryDark = typedValueColorPrimaryDark.data;
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
        getWindow().setStatusBarColor(colorPrimaryDark);
    }

    /** Button Forgot Password **/
    btnForgot.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), PasswordResetActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
            finish();
        }});

    /** Button Login **/
    btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (  ( !inputEmail.getText().toString().equals("")) && ( !inputPassword.getText().toString().equals("")) )
            {
                NetAsync(view);
            }
            else if ( ( !inputEmail.getText().toString().equals("")) )
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Password field empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else if ( ( !inputPassword.getText().toString().equals("")) )
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Email field empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Email and Password field are empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
}

private class NetCheck extends AsyncTask<String,String,Boolean>
{
    private ProgressDialog nDialog;
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute(){
        super.onPreExecute();
        nDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        nDialog.setTitle("Checking Network");
        nDialog.setMessage("Loading..");
        nDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        nDialog.setCancelable(true);
        nDialog.show();
    }

    /** Gets current device state and checks for working internet connection by trying Google **/
    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... args){
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnected()) {
            try {
                URL url = new URL("http://www.google.com");
                HttpURLConnection urlc = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                urlc.setConnectTimeout(3000);
                urlc.connect();
                if (urlc.getResponseCode() == 200) {
                    return true;
                }
            } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean th){
        if(th == true){
            nDialog.dismiss();
            new ProcessLogin().execute();
        }
        else{
            nDialog.dismiss();
            loginErrorMsg.setText("Error in Network Connection");
        }
    }
}

/** Async Task to get and send data to My Sql database through JSON respone **/
private class ProcessLogin extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject> {
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    String email,password,mac1;
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        inputEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
        inputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
        email = inputEmail.getText().toString();
        password = inputPassword.getText().toString();
        //mac1 = macmac.getText().toString();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        pDialog.setTitle("Contacting Servers");
        pDialog.setMessage("Logging in ...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... args) {
        UserFunctions userFunction = new UserFunctions();
        JSONObject json = userFunction.loginUser(email, password);
        return json;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {
        try {
            if (json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS) != null) {
                String res = json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS);
                if(Integer.parseInt(res) == 1){
                    pDialog.setMessage("Loading User Space");
                    pDialog.setTitle("Getting Data");
                    DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());
                    JSONObject json_user = json.getJSONObject("user");
                    /** Clear all previous data in SQlite database **/
                    UserFunctions logout = new UserFunctions();
                    logout.logoutUser(getApplicationContext());
                    db.addUser(json_user.getString(KEY_FIRSTNAME),json_user.getString(KEY_LASTNAME),json_user.getString(KEY_EMAIL),json_user.getString(KEY_USERNAME),json_user.getString(KEY_UID),json_user.getString(KEY_CREATED_AT));
                    /** If JSON array details are stored in SQlite it launches the User Panel **/
                    Intent upanel = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), HomeActivity.class);
                    upanel.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    pDialog.dismiss();
                    new status_login().execute();
                    startActivity(upanel);
                    /** Close Login Screen **/
                    finish();
                }else{
                    pDialog.dismiss();
                    loginErrorMsg.setText("Incorrect username or password");
                }
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
public void NetAsync(View view){
    new NetCheck().execute();
}
}
```

anyone can help me to make my application just one time login?

thanks before

Answer (score 0):

You must store the values within shared preference so that, untill the app data is cleared or no session destroyed by the user, user will be logged in within application, and the login screen will appear only once.

Answer (score 0):

in you post execute, you know that your user has logged in successfully or not. so it would not so bad to set a preference to set that login is true, so in another activity you can check the value of that shared preference value and if it true then he was logged in successfully otherwise not. so write something the following way

```
// in this method where you find your user either to be logged in or failed
 @Override
 protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {
        try {
            if (json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS) != null) {
            if (login == true) {
            SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
           editor.putBoolean(getString(R.string.login), true);
           editor.commit();
            }
        }
 }
```

and your main activity check for it as shown below

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
boolean login = getResources().getBoolean(R.string.login);
if (login) {
// do what you want to do
} else {
  // prompt for login again
}
```

know more about [SharedPreference](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html#ReadSharedPreference)

Comment: in second code can like this? 
`if (login) {
Intent upanel = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), HomeActivity.class);
startActivity(upanel);
finish();
} else {

}`

Comment: where you know that your user logged in successfully, there set the shared preference. here the R.string.login is just a key. you don't need to do it by string resources but having a string resource will make your code understandable and less conflict would occurre  with your keys as it gets more preferences for your app

Comment: and where you need to know whether your user is logged in or not, then check for that shared preference that i shown in my answer.

Comment: Error in here line http://prntscr.com/dnonwd 
1. login -> cannot resolve symbol 'login'
2. getActivity -> cannot resolve methode 'getActivity'

Comment: then just delete this getActivity().getPreference(CONTEXT_PRIVATE). use this line instead PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

Answer (score 0):

You can use a SharedPreferences object to save the login status. Once a user is successfully login you store a boolean flag, for example:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
editor.putBoolean("signed_in", true);
editor.commit();
```

Next time you will just check this value.

```
    SharedPreferences sharedPref = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    if (sharedPref.getBoolean("signed_in", false) == true){
    //user is login
    }else{
    //user not login
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
This is Your Answer

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    TextView btnForgot;
    Button btnLogin;
    EditText inputEmail;
    EditText inputPassword;
    private TextView loginErrorMsg;
    private TextView macmac, macmac1;
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    private static String KEY_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static String KEY_UID = "uid";
    private static String KEY_USERNAME = "uname";
    private static String KEY_FIRSTNAME = "fname";
    private static String KEY_LASTNAME = "lname";
    private static String KEY_EMAIL = "email";
    private static String KEY_CREATED_AT = "created_at";
    private static String MAC = "mac_0";
    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
    JSONArray products = null;
    SharedPreferences sharedPref;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("MysharePrefrence", MODE_PRIVATE);
        editor = sharedPref.edit();
        boolean login = sharedPref.getBoolean("isLogin",false);

        if (login)
        {
            Intent upanel = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), HomeActivity.class);
            upanel.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(upanel);
            finish();

        } 


        btnForgot = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        inputEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
        inputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
        btnLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
        loginErrorMsg = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.loginErrorMsg);
        TypedValue typedValueColorPrimaryDark = new TypedValue();
        MainActivity.this.getTheme().resolveAttribute(R.attr.colorPrimary, typedValueColorPrimaryDark, true);
        final int colorPrimaryDark = typedValueColorPrimaryDark.data;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
            getWindow().setStatusBarColor(colorPrimaryDark);
        }

        /** Button Forgot Password **/
        btnForgot.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), PasswordResetActivity.class);
                startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
                finish();
            }});

        /** Button Login **/
        btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (  ( !inputEmail.getText().toString().equals("")) && ( !inputPassword.getText().toString().equals("")) )
                {
                    NetAsync(view);
                }
                else if ( ( !inputEmail.getText().toString().equals("")) )
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Password field empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else if ( ( !inputPassword.getText().toString().equals("")) )
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Email field empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Email and Password field are empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private class NetCheck extends AsyncTask<String,String,Boolean>
    {
        private ProgressDialog nDialog;
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute(){
            super.onPreExecute();
            nDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            nDialog.setTitle("Checking Network");
            nDialog.setMessage("Loading..");
            nDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            nDialog.setCancelable(true);
            nDialog.show();
        }

        /** Gets current device state and checks for working internet connection by trying Google **/
        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(String... args){
            ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
            if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnected()) {
                try {
                    URL url = new URL("http://www.google.com");
                    HttpURLConnection urlc = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    urlc.setConnectTimeout(3000);
                    urlc.connect();
                    if (urlc.getResponseCode() == 200) {
                        return true;
                    }
                } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean th){
            if(th == true){
                nDialog.dismiss();
                new ProcessLogin().execute();
            }
            else{
                nDialog.dismiss();
                loginErrorMsg.setText("Error in Network Connection");
            }
        }
    }

    /** Async Task to get and send data to My Sql database through JSON respone **/
    private class ProcessLogin extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject> {
        private ProgressDialog pDialog;
        String email,password,mac1;
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            inputEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
            inputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
            email = inputEmail.getText().toString();
            password = inputPassword.getText().toString();
            //mac1 = macmac.getText().toString();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            pDialog.setTitle("Contacting Servers");
            pDialog.setMessage("Logging in ...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... args) {
            UserFunctions userFunction = new UserFunctions();
            JSONObject json = userFunction.loginUser(email, password);
            return json;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {
            try {
                if (json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS) != null) {
                    String res = json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS);
                    if(Integer.parseInt(res) == 1){
                        pDialog.setMessage("Loading User Space");
                        pDialog.setTitle("Getting Data");
                        DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());
                        JSONObject json_user = json.getJSONObject("user");
                        /** Clear all previous data in SQlite database **/
                        UserFunctions logout = new UserFunctions();
                        logout.logoutUser(getApplicationContext());
                        db.addUser(json_user.getString(KEY_FIRSTNAME),json_user.getString(KEY_LASTNAME),json_user.getString(KEY_EMAIL),json_user.getString(KEY_USERNAME),json_user.getString(KEY_UID),json_user.getString(KEY_CREATED_AT));
                        /** If JSON array details are stored in SQlite it launches the User Panel **/


                        editor.putBoolean("isLogin",true);
                        editor.commit();


                        Intent upanel = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), HomeActivity.class);
                        upanel.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                        pDialog.dismiss();
                        new status_login().execute();
                        startActivity(upanel);
                        /** Close Login Screen **/
                        finish();
                    }else{
                        pDialog.dismiss();
                        loginErrorMsg.setText("Incorrect username or password");
                    }
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    public void NetAsync(View view){
        new NetCheck().execute();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hope , this will help you

Comment: Clear your SharePreference when you Logout

Comment: not work sir... after I close my program it always need login again

Comment: sorry sir it works ... how to delete SharePreference?

Comment: SharedPreferences _SP = getSharedPreferences("MySharePreference", MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor  _EDITOR = _SP.edit();
            _EDITOR.clear();

            or if you not want to clear your SharePrefrence

            _EDITOR.putBoolean("isLogin",false);
            _EDITOR.commit();